# How to give two background-image with out any stretch but need to repeat

Tags: css

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="headerBanner">
        <a href="{$websiteUrl}index.html"><img src="img/NewTopBanner.jpg" width="885" height="190" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    background:url('img/header/CRC_Website_TopBannerLeftStretch.jpg'),url("img/header/CRC_Website_TopBannerRightStretch.jpg");
    background-position:left, right;
    background-size:50% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.headerBanner {
    width: 885px;
}
```

This is my HTMl and css code.

it works, but this two background images stretches to middle. I want this two images(left,right) not stretched and repeat to middle of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#leftHalf {
   background: url(images/bg-1.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
#rightHalf {
   background: url(images/bg-2.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Try this one, (not tested). It may be help you.